# Concentration of measure vs large deviation

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, large-deviation-theory, concentration-of-measure

When reading some probability publications I am always not sure why they call this or that inequality a 'concentration inequality' or 'large deviation inequality'. For me these (concentration of measure and large deviation theory) just describe the same phenomenon. So I ask, is there a formal difference between concentration and large deviation inequalities? Or are these really different concepts?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From my point of view concentration inequalities and large deviation theory are indeed different concepts - but since there are a lot of well-known concentration inequalities which have the form of large deviation estimates it is not surprising that there is sometimes no strict distinction between both notions.

*Concentration inequalites* are inequalities that bound probabilies of deviations by the random variable $X$ from its mean or median, i.e. upper bounds for probabilities of the form

$$\mathbb{P}\bigg( |X-\mathbb{E}X)| > r \bigg) \quad \text{or} \quad \mathbb{P}\bigg( |X-m(X)| > r \bigg)$$

where $m(X)$ denotes the median of $X$. Some basic concentration inequalites are the Markov inequality,

$$\mathbb{E}(|X| \geq r) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(|X|)}{r},$$

and the Tschebysheff inequality,

$$\mathbb{E}(|X-\mathbb{E}X| \geq r) \leq \frac{\text{var} \, X}{r^2}.$$

Often one is interested in the asymptotics of such probabilites, i.e. the asymptotic decay of

$$\mathbb{P}\bigg( |X_n-\mathbb{E}(X_n)| > r \bigg)$$

as $n \to \infty$. Now here comes *large deviation theory* into play: Large deviation theory yields asymptotic estimates of the form

$$\mathbb{P}\bigg( |X_n-\mathbb{E}(X_n)| > r \bigg) \leq e^{-n I(r)} \tag{1}$$

where $I(r) \geq 0$ is called the rate function. The [Chernoff bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound), [Hoeffding inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) or [McDiarmid's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDiarmid%27s_inequality#McDiarmid.27s_inequality) are well-known results of this type. This means that large deviation theory provides estimates on an *exponential* scale. However, concentration inequalities do not need to be of the form $(1)$. A different approach uses so-called concentration functions.

Let me finally mention that large deviation theory deals more generally with the asymptotic behavior of probabilites of the form

$$\mathbb{P} \bigg( X_n \in A \bigg),$$

for some fixed set $A$, on an exponential scale, i.e.

$$\mathbb{P} \bigg(X_n \in A \bigg) \approx \exp \bigg(-n \cdot I(A) \bigg).$$

Obviously, the estimates in $(1)$ are a particular case if we choose $A=[\mathbb{E}(X_n)-r,\mathbb{E}(X_n)+r]$.

Comment: Very usefull answer! Thanks a lot. I will wait some time before accepting the answer.

Comment: By the notation $X_n$, do you imply that it is the average of $n$ independent copies of the random variable?

Comment: @elexhobby No, $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an arbitrary sequence of random variables. But, in fact, there are several concentration inequalities which focus on this setting (i.e. $X_n = \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j/n$ where $Y_j$ are independent identically distributed random variables), e.g. the Hoeffding inequality.